# Java regex, replace certain characters except

Tags: java, regex, swing

I have this string "u2x4m5x7" and I want replace all the characters but a number followed by an x with "".
The output should be: 
"2x5x"
Just the number followed by the x.
But I am getting this:
"2x45x7"

I'm doing this:

```
String string = "u2x4m5x7";

String s = string.replaceAll("[^0-9+x]","");
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a one-liner using `String#replaceAll` with two replacements:

```
System.out.println(string.replaceAll("\\d+(?!x)", "").replaceAll("[^x\\d]", ""));
```

Here is another working solution.  We can iterate the input string using a formal pattern matcher with the pattern `\d+x`.  This is the whitelist approach, of trying to match the variable combinations we want to keep.

```
String input = "u2x4m5x7";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+x");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

while(m.find()) {
    b.append(m.group(0));
}

System.out.println(b)
```

This prints:

```
2x5x
```

Comment: @HarshalParekh Yes, it can be done using `String#replaceAll`.  But keep in mind that `replaceAll` uses a pattern matcher under the hood, so the second part of my answer is not as ugly as it might appear.

Comment: This one is the one :D, thank you so much!! You guys are awesome!.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this would be much simpler by searching to get the match rather than replacing all non matches, but here is a possible solution, though it may be missing a few cases:

```
\d(?!x)|[^0-9x]|(?<!\d)x
```

https://regex101.com/r/v6udph/1

Basically it will:

- `\d(?!x)` -- remove any digit not followed by an `x`
- `[^0-9x]` -- remove all non-x/digit characters
- `(?<!\d)x` -- remove all `x`'s not preceded by a digit

But then again, grabbing from `\dx` would be much simpler

Answer (score 2):

[Capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) what you need to `$1` OR [any character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) and replace with captured `$1` (empty if `|.` matched).

```
String s = string.replaceAll("(\\d+x)|.", "$1");
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KHBHCk/1) or a [Java demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##XYy9DoIwFIVn@hQ3jQNEbaLROBAHB58AN3Go0GCxf6EXhCjPjo0uxrOc4Xznq3nHl3V5n6ZCce9BDyfhkTxJ5NqrkgV45Biqs7IEzaWBOMNGmup8Ad5UPgG8NfbhoQ4iprip2LEvhENpDYmCJvriwfOpPdB23W/0tt/R9GcNw5dgjXCKF@KgVEzjPC/nffJidAF0tqJJSuAv2eBRaGZbZC78UZnYBywayThNbw)